# Test for changing mean

Tags: time-series, change-point

I want to test whether a time series is better described as IID normal or as IID normal in two segments separated by a change point, with the mean and variance different in the two segments. If I have N observations and no prior information about where the breakpoint occurs, I can fit separate Gaussians for a changepoint at observation 2, 3, ..., N. The likelihood of this model will be higher than the model with a single Gaussian. How much higher should it be to prefer the model with a change point?

Comment: I was curious why you do not do a test for a structural break at this point if you suspect one is occurring?

Comment: I can answer if you update your question, clarifying (1) Do you know the location of the change point exactly, or is it to be inferred? (2) Could you be more specific about what "prefer" means? Would loglik1 > loglik2 qualify os does it have to cross some evidence threshold, penalizing model complexity etc.?

Comment: @JonasLindeløv I don't know where the changepoint occurs or whether there is a changepoint. There needs to penalty for including a changepoint (otherwise a model with a changepoint will always have a greater likelihood and be chosen), so my question is what form the penalty should have.